# Having issues formatting a specific Date/Time format

Tags: java, parsing, date, time

I'm having issues formatting the following date/time:

```
2013-01-10T17:04:24.3787635-02:00
```

Now, I understand `2013-01-10` is the date (obviously).

`17:04:24.3787635` probably time, though I have no idea what the numbers after the dot mean.

`-02:00` I assume it's the time zone (GMT).

How can I parse this in java? (maybe using JodaTime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) to parse this date:

```
String time = "2013-01-10T17:04:24.3787635-02:00";
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZ");
DateTime dateTime = df.parseDateTime(time);
```

The numbers after the dot (`.`) are the fractions of seconds denoted by `S` in `JodaTime's` [DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html). `Z` represents the timezone pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Though I have one last question. When I execute `dateTime.getZone().getID()`, it returns me `America/Sao_Paulo`. I was expecting `GMT-3`. Is there a way for it to return me what I expect, or it just returns me the place where the timezone is applied as reference?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this pattern:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"
```

Which can parse date in this format:

```
2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00
```

Although, `3787635` in your source string is troublesome. It doesn't look like milliseconds.

Take a look at [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for additional details on patterns.

You can also try [`DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseDateTime%28java.lang.String%29) which returns a `java.util.Calendar` object.

```
DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("2013-01-10T17:04:24.3787635-02:00").getTime()
```

The above statement executes without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

The format of your time string is the ISO8601 format.  The JodaTime class `ISODateTimeFormat` will support that format directly.  You will lose any accuracy beyond millisecond, however.

```
String time = "2013-01-10T17:04:24.3787635-02:00";
DateTime dateTime = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().parseDateTime(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

This format can be parsed correctly only with javax.xml.XMLGregorianCalendar. You cannot use SimpleDateFormat because it accepts SSS as number of milliseconds, not as fractional part of a second.

```
    String s = "2013-01-10T17:04:24.3787635-02:00";
    DatatypeFactory dtf = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
    Date date = dtf.newXMLGregorianCalendar(s).toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
```